# Parse `df` output for `/dev/disk/by-uuid/xxx`

Tags: command-line, bash

I would like to ask you why this command work

```
df -P /dev/sda1 | grep /dev/sda1 | awk '{ print $5}' | sed 's/%//g'
```

But not this one?

```
df -P /dev/disk/by-uuid/0E5E17800E5E1780 | grep /dev/disk/by-uuid/0E5E17800E5E1780 | awk '{ print $5}' | sed 's/%//g'
```

Something to change or is impossible that work with uuid?

This is my full script

```
#!/bin/bash
inputa=90 
#outputa=$(df -P /dev/sda1 | grep /dev/sda1 | awk '{ print $5}' | sed 's/%//g')
outputa=$(df -P /dev/disk/by-uuid/0E5E17800E5E1780 | grep /dev/disk/by-uuid/0E5E17800E5E1780 | awk '{ print $5}' | sed 's/%//g') 

if  [ "$inputa -lt $outputa" ]
then 
     find /home/user/Documents/ipcams/ipcam2 -type f -name "*.mp4" -mtime +25 -exec rm {} \;
    (date +"%Y-%m-%d Heure:  %H-%M-%S") >> /home/user/ipcam.log
      echo Pourcentage $outputa "%" >> /home/user/ipcam.log

else echo rien

fi
```

Have a great day

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that although `df` shows information about the device specified by the UUID, the first column of its output still refers to it by the `/dev/sdXY` block device name - so the `grep` fails to match.

In fact, there's no need to use `grep` at all - you can use `awk` to skip the header line (and even to remove the `%` sign):

```
$ df -P /dev/sda1 | awk 'NR == 2 { print substr($5,1,length($5)-1) }'
80

$ df -P /dev/disk/by-uuid/79b5546e-5b3e-4299-becb-5f0cad06cf5f | awk 'NR == 2 { print substr($5,1,length($5)-1) }'
80
```

Answer (score 1):

`/dev/disk/by-uuid/0E5E17800E5E178` is a link to a Device, which may or may not contain a Filesystem. `df` works only on filesystems, not raw devices. From `man df`:

```
df displays the amount of disk space available on the file system containing each file name argument.
```